# Change default instance disk size in the kubernetes-jenkins plugin

Tags: docker, jenkins-plugins, kubernetes

When we spin up an instance using the kubernetes jenkins plugin, the disk space default to 10G. Is there anyway to change it?

We are running 1.2.0-0.13 and using dockers on CentOS7.

Comment: How are you spinning it up? kube-up?

Comment: Sorry was spinning it up using the kubernetes jenkins plugin

Comment: Can you be more specific? There are many.

Comment: this particular one: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Kubernetes+Plugin

Comment: This seems like an issue that should be raised with the plugin maintainers as it doesn't appear to be a kubernetes issue.

Comment: If you are using GKE/GCE, you could [resize the created persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk). However, your best bet is to check with the plugin developers.